# How to add CORS to firebase onCall functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

I am trying to send email with Firebase using an `onCall` function. The function is triggered by a form submission in a website. This is my code

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors')({
  origin: true
});
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'xxx',
  port: xxx,
  secure: true, // use SSL
  auth: {
    user: 'xxx',
    pass: 'xxx' 
  }
});


exports.sendEmail = functions.https.onCall((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    const email = req.email;
    const name = req.name;
    const message = req.message;
    const subject = req.subject
    const sender = `xxx`;
    const recipient = `xxx`;
    const mailOptions = {
      from: sender,
      to: recipient,
      subject: `New web enquiry!`,
      html: `<h1>Notification from ${subject}</h1>
              <p>
                <b>Name: </b>${name}<br>
                <b>Email: </b>${email}<br>
                <b>Message: </b>${message}<br>
              </p>`
    };
    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return res.status(403).send(error.toString());
      }
      console.log("Email Sent!")
      return res.status(200).send('Sent');
    });
  });
});
```

When the function triggers, I get this error

```
> Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined
>     at /workspace/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:40
>     at optionsCallback (/workspace/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:199:9)
>     at corsMiddleware (/workspace/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:204:7)
>     at /workspace/index.js:880:3
>     at fixedLen (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:120:41)
>     at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:400:32
>     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Interestingly, the same code with an `onRequest` function works ok.

Can anyone shine some light into this?

thanks

Comment: Hi @M4trixDev I have posted an answer below. Please go through it and if you have any queries/ questions you can let me know.

Comment: I think this is because cors expects request and response and callable functions are passing data and context.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody else who has arrived here searching firebase callable functions cors errors, here's my checklist:

- Ensure the function is deployed correctly.
- Ensure the function name is correct.
- Ensure the function code itself is not throwing an error. [Use the
  emulator to help](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell#invoke_https_callable_functions)
- Ensure your regions match

Note : All these can lead to cors errors, it's better if you can find the error in functions logs rather than having in the illusion it's a CORS error.

Now after this checklist is done, let's get to the question `“the same code with an onRequest function works ok. So why not with onCall?”`.

Firebase has two different ways for creating HTTP Cloud Functions, one is the `onRequest` method, and the other one is using the `onCall` method.
Both of these functions create an HTTP endpoint that you can call. The big difference is in how you call them.
The onRequest functions follow the more regular nodejs API (Kinda like express) where you call the endpoint, and inside, you get the request and response, and you work with that like most node js applications.

```
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("I'm a Firebase HTTP Function");
});
```

The onCall function is a special wrapper on top of that, that takes advantage of the Firebase JavaScript SDK from both UI and server-side, which will handle most of the complex parts for you, like automatically passing the state of the user’s authentication from the client without you having to do extra work. It passes data and context as parameters.

```
export const sayHello = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // data holds the 'body' being sent
  // context holds metadata like headers, authentication, etc.
  return { message: 'I am a callable function' };
});
```

They both work well, as a general guideline,  use the onRequest functions when doing server-to-server communication, like when trying to connect another backend system to cloud functions. And  use the onCall functions when calling Cloud Functions from the UI, that way, the Firebase JS SDK can handle authentication.

**So if HTTPS Callable functions are called from App / website like form submission website in your case, you have to call the reference to your callable function (`firebase.functions().httpsCallable(‘your-function-name’)` there in your html page, include the firebaseConfig, handle the client error like shown in this [example](https://medium.com/wesionary-team/callable-function-how-to-write-and-deploy-a-callable-function-9eb8c109186e). You can also follow this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) which outlines how to call callable functions from App.**

1. Write and deploy the function on the server-side. Look how they take
   two parameters data, context and return data to client as JSON
   encoded.
2. Handle errors  To ensure the client gets useful error details,
   return errors from a callable by throwing (or returning a Promise
   rejected with) an instance of functions.https.HttpsError. The error
   has a code attribute that can be one of the values listed at
   functions.https.HttpsError. The errors also have a string message,
   which defaults to an empty string. If an error other than HttpsError
   is thrown from your functions, your client instead receives an error
   with the message INTERNAL and the code internal.
3. Deploy the callable function After you save a completed callable
   function within index.js, run

   firebase deploy --only
   functions:addMessage
4. Now in the client side,  set up the environment whatever you want to
   do, manually require both Firebase core and Cloud Functions, include
   the FirebaseConfig from the Firebase console.
5. Finally call the function in the client, by calling the reference
   `httpsCallable(functions,’functionName’)`;

If HTTPS Callable functions are not called from client App/ website it must be called using the POST method, the Content-Type must be application/json or application/json; charset=utf-8, and the body must contain a field called data for the data to be passed to the method. All of this has been documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference). This section provides a specification for the HTTPS request and response formats used by the client SDKs to implement the API.

Comment: Excellent explanation @priyashree-bhadra !!